# Perl can't find module listed in same directory as script

Tags: perl, module, package

I need to keep any custom modules in the same-ish directory as my script.

I keep getting this error suggesting that Perl can't "see" the module I'm declaring

> Global symbol "$employment_type" requires explicit package name at early_enrollments_by_term.pl line 260.
>
> Execution of early_enrollments_by_term.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

My module is `Hash.pm` and is in directory `/home/pgb2/canvas/canvas-sis-feeds/scripts/lib/Custom`

#### Hash.pm

```
package Custom::Hash;
```

My script is `early_enrollments_by_term.pl` and lives in `/home/pgb2/canvas/canvas-sis-feeds/scripts/`

#### early_enrollments_by_term.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

use DBI;

use lib qw(/home/pgb2/canvas/canvas-sis-feeds/scripts/lib);

use Custom::Hash;

my $enrollment_type = $Custom::Hash::enrollment_hash{$role};  # line 259
print "\nenrollment_type: $employment_type\n";                # line 260
```

Would anyone be able to tell why it's not finding the module?

Comment: Note that recent versions of Perl (you do not say which one you use), that is 5.26 and above, do not include `.` (local directory) in `@INC` so by default  a module in same directory as script will not be found by default. See https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Project:Perl/Dot-In-INC-Removal for all details. You do not have the problem per se since you provide the full path, but that will make things complicated when you want to move your script+libraries elsewhere. See the `FindBin` module to help with that case.

Comment: The error messages indicates that the module is found. The problem is that the <strike>module</strike> script contains a compile-time error [edited]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although you have shown very little of your code, 
the problem would presumably be that you have declared `$enrollment_type` and tried to use `$employment_type`, which has not been declared

Had perl been unable to find the module, it is the `use Custom::Hash` statement that would throw the error

Comment: Thank you, I didn't even notice that! This was originally someone else's script that "wasn't working". Thank you again!